# Size of Div in CSS

Tags: css

I have a main div that it re-sizes with re-sizing window. I want to add 2 div inside the main div (float left and right). left one width is 165  and right one width is the rest size of main div. can I simply use something in CSS?

```
#leftDiv{
    height:100%;
    width:165px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#244378;
}

#rightDiv {
    height:100%;
    width:100% - 165px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#244378;
}
```

Comment: Something like this? [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/Em973/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want do it this way, you can use the CSS3 `calc` property, but keep in mind that this isn't supported in all browsers:

```
   #rightDiv {
        height:100%;
        width:calc(100% - 165px);
        float:left;
        background-color:#244378;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No! you cannot use a value like "100% -165px".
Instead you can just remove "float:left" and "width:" from #rightDiv.
That should work for your case.

Comment: Yes you can, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remofe `float:left` from `#rightDiv` and set `width` to `auto` in this way:

```
#rightDiv {
    height:100%;
    width:auto;
    background-color:#ff0000;
}
```

If you do this, the right div will always appear near the left div and will have a dynamic width.

Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/b9BrB/1/